# How to get back data(JSON) in ajax's success method from java code

Tags: java, json, ajax, jsp

I send data from **JSP** via **ajax** into the java.in **java**, I stored data into **JSON** Array and send it back to my **JSP** page but I don't know how I retrieve that data into **JSP's ajax** success method to check whether the user inserted or not.

**index.jsp**

```
  <script>            
        $(document).ready(function(){
              $('#btnSub').click(function(){
                var url = ""
                var data = "";
                var method;

                url = 'add.jsp';
                data = $("#formStudent").serialize();
                method = 'POST';

                //AJAX CALL
                $.ajax ( {
                url: url,
                data: data,
                dataType: 'JSON',
                type: method,
                success: function (data){
                  **here i want get back data from the java code(add.jsp)**
                }
            });//ajax close
          });
        });
  </script>
```

**add.jsp** (java code)

```
<%
    String sname = request.getParameter("sname");
    String course = request.getParameter("course");
    String fee = request.getParameter("fee");
    System.out.println(sname);
    System.out.println(course);
    System.out.println(fee);
    //Database 
    String DriverClass = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jspajaxjasondb";
    String user = "root";
    String password = "";
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;

    Class.forName(DriverClass);
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
    System.out.println("Connection hefbejhbfehfbehj");

    ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into records(sname,course,fee) values(?,?,?)");
    ps.setString(1, sname);
    ps.setString(2, course);
    ps.setString(3, fee);

    int i = ps.executeUpdate();
    JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

    if(i > 0){
        obj.put("pass", "success");
        list.add(obj);
        **send record to index.jsp**
        out.println(list.toJSONString());
    }
    else{
        obj.put("fail", "error");
        out.println(list.toJSONString());
    }
    out.flush();
%>
```

Comment: what does `data` has in it in ajax function ? can you post that as well?

Comment: Data in ajax function is coming from a webform and that I pass through ajax into the java class for insertion operation and if inserted then data success msg will get back to my JSP so I show that on my webForm